# How to show a progress bar or a loader on post action of share extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-extensions

I created a share extension for my application in Swift. Now I have to call an API and send the title and image to the server. I am able to call the API from the `didSelectPost` method of `ShareViewController` but it is taking some time to complete the upload. My question is how can I show a progress bar or an activity indicator over there so that I can show to user that something is happening? Like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkutM.jpg).

Also, can you please tell me the significance of the method `completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler:)`? I read the documentation of this method but I can not use it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag drop activity indicator in your interface builder.
2. Set it horizontally and vertically in container from there.
3. Create its outlet as "`@iboutlet weak var ibactivity : UIActivity..`".
4. On hit of api, call `ibactivity.startAnimating()' & also write self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false if reqd`.
5. On success or failure of response `ibactivity.stopAnimating()` and set it hidden.

you are done..!!